# Find and remove specific element using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have javascript that generates the following HTML

```
<div class='rightbox'>
 <div class'testBox'>

 </div>


</div>
```

Now i have a button that when pressed should remove the div whos class is `testbox`. Now even though it is in this case it is not always that the `testBox` is the first child within the `rightbox`.

So how do i find and remove it? and then afterwards test if it is present as a child within the `rightbox`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use, e.g., [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) to find your element and then a combination of [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode) and [`removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild) to delete it.

```
var el = document.querySelector( '.testBox' );
el.parentNode.removeChild( el );
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/guMzm/)

---

*Edit 2018*:

In the meanwhile support for [`remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) has landed <sup>(In all browsers, but IE)</sup>, so the above code can be reduced to the following:

```
document.querySelector( '.testBox' ).remove();
```

Note, that you should check, whether the selected node actually exists. Otherwiese both snippets will throw an error.

Comment: but is this useable to the child node?

Comment: @Marc What do you mean?

Comment: Does this approach introduce memory leaks? Because the dom element isn't destroyed in memory, it's only disassociated from the parent node.

Comment: @JamieButler There is no way to really destroy an element in JavaScript. As soon as there are no references to that element anymore, the garbage collection will take care of it. In the above example, `el` is probably the last remaining reference, so you should set it to `null` finally (or exit the scope in which it is valid).

Comment: @Sirko OK sweet, good to know.

Answer (score 5):

```
var testBoxes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.testBox'));

testBoxes.forEach(function(testBox) {
    testBox.parentNode.removeChild(testBox);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var el;
for(var i = 0, ceiling = els.length; i < ceiling; i++) {
    el = els[i];
    if(el.className == "testbox") {
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
        break;
    }
}

var presentAsChildWithinRightbox = false;
for(var i = 0, ceiling = els.length; i < ceiling; i++) {
    el = els[i];
    if(el.className == "rightbox") {
        var childNodes = el.childNodes;
        for(var j = 0, ceiling2 = childNodes.length; j < ceiling2; j++) {
            if(childNodes[j].className == "testbox") {
                presentAsChildWithinRightbox = true;
                j = ceiling2;
                i = ceiling;
            }
        }
    }
}
if(presentAsChildWithinRightbox)
    alert("A div with classname childbox has a child div with classname testbox");
else
    alert("A div with classname childbox does not have a child div with classname testbox");
```

Answer (score -7):

Try this

```
$(".rightBox").find("div").eq(0).remove();
$(".rightBox").find("div.testBox").remove();
```

Note: This is implemented using jQuery

Comment: that is Jquery and not pure javascript

Comment: @ Marc : I have specified it in my answer. and you should have read it. It will be better if anyone can justify the downvoting even after explaining the scenario in the answer itself.

Comment: @GaneshPandhere Your answer was rightfully downvoted. Perhaps **you should have read** the title of the question, which reads **using pure javascript**, meaning not using additional libraries like jQuery, Prototype, etc

Comment: @GaneshPandhere Do note i did not downvote you. i just stated that your solution is not pure javascript.